# nodemon app crashed : Error code- MODULE_NOT_FOUND, requirestack: [ ]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

When I am running **nodemon** run start it is giving me the following error
I am running this on macos. Not sure if that matters or not.
**ERROR**

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/jarvis/Documents/Backend/mongoTelusko/run'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:768:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**This is my app.js file**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/AlienDBex'

    enter code here

const app = express()

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true})
const con = mongoose.connection

con.on('open', function(){
    console.log('Connected...')
})
```

**This is my package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "mongotelusko",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "malay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.5",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
```

Since you have specified "start" script in package.json, `npm start` command automatically calls `nodemon app.js`
However, you can also run the `nodemon app.js` manually which also has the same effect.

Wrong: nodemon run start
Correct: `nodemon app.js` or `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

You're running `nodemon run start`, which tells `nodemon` to execute `run` (run.js) with argument `start`. Did you mean to use `npm run start`? Hint: You can also use `npm start` as a shortcut.

Comment: Basically, I wanted to check my connection with mongo. (app.js file)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error while I'm trying to run the code on my Mac.

I found why it is showing me this error:

- first reason is that I've installed Node.js through an installation pack downloaded from [nodejs.org][1], but I should've installed node from the **Terminal**.
- second reason is that I found out that I was trying to run the file from a different folder. I was in folder `/users/practice/file-manager/frontend` - trying to run the code from file which is located in directory `/users/practice/file-manager/backend` - the main reason which caused this error.

As a solution that worked for me:

- make sure you've installed Node.js from terminal
- make sure you're in the right directory when you're trying to run the `.js` file.

Maybe this information helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution after trying new files, etc... didnt work. Then starting from the beginning:

- deleting node.js and clearing cache about npm (from appdata)
- creating new file and being sure about path you can confirm with 'cd'
- trying to re-install npm_modules at my project folder.(npm install)

Then it worked.