# How to resolve Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli' in deploying to Azure web service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions, node-modules, nodemon

I'm trying to deploy an Nodejs - React app to Azure using Github actions.
It works fine on my computer, but when I deploy to Azure, I keep getting this nodemon error:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2023-06-05T16:03:30.613684171Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2023-06-05T16:03:30.613687871Z      export PORT=8080
2023-06-05T16:03:30.613691971Z fi
2023-06-05T16:03:30.613695471Z 
2023-06-05T16:03:30.615420031Z npm start
2023-06-05T16:03:32.033435232Z npm info using n******@9.6.4
2023-06-05T16:03:32.036983955Z npm info using n******@v16.20.0
2023-06-05T16:03:32.146052335Z 
2023-06-05T16:03:32.146153939Z > m******@1.0.0 start
2023-06-05T16:03:32.146164039Z > nodemon
2023-06-05T16:03:32.146168639Z 
2023-06-05T16:03:32.372833495Z node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1029
2023-06-05T16:03:32.372899597Z   throw err;
2023-06-05T16:03:32.372906198Z   ^
2023-06-05T16:03:32.372910198Z 
2023-06-05T16:03:32.372989500Z Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli'
2023-06-05T16:03:32.372997901Z Require stack:
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373001901Z - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/nodemon
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373005601Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373009301Z     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373013001Z     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373016601Z     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373031602Z     at Object. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/nodemon:3:13)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373035702Z     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373039302Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373043002Z     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373046602Z     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373050203Z     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373053903Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373057503Z   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/nodemon' ]
2023-06-05T16:03:32.373061503Z }
```

I tried to reinstall nodemon and all the packages, I tried adding explicit nodeomn global installation in my yml file, but nothing seemed to work yet.
This is the workflow configuration file:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ------    # set this to your application's name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: '16.20.0'                # set this to the node version to use

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
        cache: 'npm'

    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
        npx webpack
        

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: node-app
        path: .

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: node-app

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure WebApp'
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

and this is my package.json : {

```
  "name": "mich-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "hotloader": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --port 5000",
    "start": "npm start",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=11.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.6.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.28.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the nodemon package to work and to resolve the No module found error, Add the below start script  in your package.json like below:-

```json
"scripts": {

"start": "nodemon app.js"
```

Above script [**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789133/nodemon-app-crashed-error-code-module-not-found-requirestack)

**My package.json:-**

```json
{
  "name": "myexpressapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

I installed my npm packages and nodemon package in my express app cloned from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) with the commands below:-

```js
npm install
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

[image]

My complete yml github action code [**here**](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

Code [**reference**](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AppService/node.js-webapp-on-azure.yml)

**My yml:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - siliconwebapp3

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm install -g nodemon
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'siliconwebapp3'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_40FC8384752945E78062F5C2FD11CE2D }}
          package: .
```

In the above yml workflow, I have added nodemon install command too:-

```yaml
 run: |
          npm install
          npm install -g nodemon
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]